# How can I make my custom HTML widgets show differently for different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

bear with me here-- I'm trying to learn HTML/CSS.

I have this how-to site, [dropshipstepbystep.com](http://dropshipstepbystep.com/).  I wanted to top-line the '3 steps to success' on my home page, so I created custom HTML widgets in the 'Our Focus' section of the Zerif Lite theme.  I'm sure the way I did this is pretty terrible, but on my desktop, I've pretty much acheived the look I want.

Now I need to be able to change the way the widgets/blocks appear for smaller screen sizes.  I know I can't use inline-CSS for @media, so how should I go about this?

Please explain like I am 5.  Thanks in advance!

PS: Don't know if it helps, but here's how I wrote the first custom CSS widget...

```html
<div style= "padding-top: 25px; width: 100%; display: block; margin-bottom: 50px;">
<div style="width:78%; padding-right: 2%; display: inline-block; float: left;">
<h4 style="align: left; line-height:1.5;">Hey!  I'm Zach, and I created Dropship Step by Step to show you exactly how I build and execute a dropshipping project in 2017.  If you find my content useful, I have two things to ask of you: (1) Share it with anyone you know who would also find it valuable, and (2) if you choose to use a service I recommend, please <u>click</u> the link I provide.  Some of the services I recommend pay me referral credits, which is how I keep my content free.  If you don't click, they can't track!</h4>
</div>
<div style="width:18%; padding-left: 2%; display: inline-block; float: left; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle;">
<img src="http://www.dropshipstepbystep.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/IMG_4701.png" style="margin-top: -25px; border-radius: 50%;">
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: block;">
<h1 style="padding-top: 50px;"><u>
3 STEPS TO DROPSHIP SUCCESS</u>
</h1>
</div>
<div style= "padding-top: 25px; width: 100%; display: block; margin-bottom: 100px;">
<div style="width:33%; padding-right: 2%; display: inline-block; float: left;">
<img src="http://www.dropshipstepbystep.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Screen-Shot-2017-08-25-at-10.23.39-PM_clipped_rev_1-8.png">
</div>
<div style="width:63%; padding-left: 2%; display: inline-block; float: left;">
<br><h2 style="font-weight: bold;">Find a Product to Sell</h2>
<p style="align: left; line-height:1.5;">I'm going to show you how I find inspiration for product ideas, and how I test my ideas quickly.  The goal is to take something generic and cheap looking, then market in a way that will totally change people's perceptions.  The dash cam on the left is a perfect example.  I get them for $20 and sell them for $60, and they're actually really nice!  I use one myself.</p>
<p style="align: left; line-height:1.5;">You can find many inexpensive products to promote for free via <a href="http://dropshipstepbystep.com/go/aliexpress">AliExpress</a>.  Alternatively, <a href="http://dropshipstepbystep.com/go/salehoo">SaleHoo</a> will tell you exactly how well products are selling around the web, at what profit margin, and what supplier will dropship them for you ($69/year).  Plus,
 you can find American-based suppliers, so your customers don't have to wait weeks for products to arrive.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can use for your problem is the grid system in Bootstrap. You can find the information for this here- https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/
and in various other tutorials.
You basically just have to assign the required space on your screen for the widgets differently for small, extra small and medium sized devices.

Other than this if you want to space your elements on your screen, you can use flexbox for that. There are various tutorials available for this as well.

Both can be used together. I am sure you will be able to solve your problem with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with learning CSS media queries and how to it for responsive website development. I recommend you can learn it from W3Cschool, below is the reference link:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

first of all please use CSS from the external file. Currently, you are using inline CSS which is hard to use in @media query.
Once your layout is done then use @media query for different devices.